# How to convert a JSON request into a list of specific format n spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arraylist

I have a request JSON list like this:

```
[
 {
  Id: 0,
  values: [a, b, c, d]
 },
 {
  Id: 1,
  values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
 },
 .
 .
 .
]
```

How do I convert this to a list like this:

```
[
 {
  Name: a,
  Count: 1
 },
 {
  Name: b,
  Count: 2
 }
 {
  Name: c,
  Count: 3
 }
 {
  Name: d,
  Count: 4
 }
]
```

I have a dto class consisting of name and count attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the result you want is a list of your DTO Class.

For this you would have to have a DTO Class like this one:

```
public class TestRequest {
    private String name;
    private Integer count;
}
```

An example of the original DTO class could be:

```
public class TestRequestDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private List<String> values;
}
```

The result would be a list of your DTO Class like this:

```
        List<TestRequestDTO> dtoClassList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TestRequest> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < dtoClassList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < dtoClassList.get(i).getValues().size(); j++) {
                if (i+1 != dtoClassList.size()) {
                    toReturn.add(TestRequest.builder()
                            .name(dtoClassList.get(i).getValues().get(j))
                            .count(dtoClassList.get(i + 1).getValues().get(j))
                            .build());
                }
            }
        }
```

The resulting request would be as follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "a",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "b",
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, I want a list of my DTO class and I do have a DTO class of the above structure. But how do I make this dynamic instead of doing for each values list element because I have a long list of values list objects?

Comment: The previous answer was an example for you to modify to suit your problem, however I have edited the answer to resemble your initial problem. Please note that with the information you provided at the beginning I'm not able to know the structure you have set up. Best regards!

Comment: That's great! I'm delighted to hear that. Please close the question if it has been answered so that other users can benefit if they have a similar problem. You can find information about this at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a zip on the value lists to create a list of tuples containing the nth element of each.

Comment: I cannot seem to use zip in my spring boot java application. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to generate a set using members of two different sets in the original JSON file according to positions. The code will rather long if you try to do it in Java.

It is easy to accomplish this in SPL, the open-source Java package. Three lines of code are enough:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVGLL.png)

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as convert.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call convert()");
st.execute();
…
```